# Storing all the data in one postgres table with partitioning

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I saw a bit of an unusual database design and need some help understanding the challenges.

The design is

1. DB is Postgres
2. All the data needed for a HR application - right from Employee data , Timesheet , Invoice etc are stored in a single table
3. The table has EntityType ,ID,  Data ( jsonb ) columns . The table is partitioned by Entity Type.

Is putting all data into one table with a partition , good design ?

What challenges would we face ?

We are looking at half a million new records per week.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you describe seems to be the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model. IMHO it is a **absolutely horrible data model**. Others disagree. You should google it, become familiar,  build a test set (say a M:M relationship), then make your own decision.

Comment: "*Employee data , Timesheet , Invoice etc are stored in a single table*" that's a horrible database model. So, no, that is not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

This schema is called EAV (Entity Attribute Value), sometimes OpenSchema but also referred to as database in a database antipattern and in some blog post called EAVil schema. The reason people are tempted to use it is the flexibility it provides in extending the schema.

The number of rows you are inserting now will probably already or soon lead to serious performance problems retrieving data although i havent tried partitioning yet. Still i am convinced these EAVs dont scale as well as regular normalized schemas do.

Besides that queries are much harder to write on an EAV schema, you are making all values typeless (unless spending serious effort on this), non indexable, data constraints will be harder or impossible so data integrity is at risk (age: -30 ) etc etc.

If you want a good overview and a good advice read Bill Karwins' book SQL Antipatterns  who writes several pages on the EAV subject. Also Tom Kyte from Oracle is a strong advocate against EAV and there are many others and their criticism holds up. Relational databases aren't suited for this kind of schema and you should use ordinary tables.